# Unable to ask a question in this forum

Tags: discussion

I am not able to ask a proper question in this forum.

Can this be fixed please?

Comment: If you have trouble joining the chat room, please add the specific problem you see/error you get.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, looks like a fellow mod and I gave you different feedback, sorry for that.

Just ask a new question about how to run the Docker daemon on the main site. It might help to also explain how you installed the `docker` binary (from docker.com or from Homebrew, probably).